# how to exclude specific file from onedirve syncing

Tags: windows, sync, group-policy, onedrive

I know how to exclude files with specific extensions, but files that doesn't have them how to exclude them by exact filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, you can add key REG_SZ with value with that filename!

in regedit(you can create that path if it's not exist yet):

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\OneDrive\EnableODIgnoreListFromGPO
```

for example:

item(string): 1
value: myLog

and restart OneDrive

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to define the files you wish to exclude.

Then move them away from One Drive to a neutral and separate folder.

They will delete from One Drive and no longer sync.

Comment: exclude within onedrive settings not working for me

Comment: As I noted - move the file outside of One Drive.  That will work.

Comment: You may find the ordinary approach to solving this issue is better than Registry changes which have no guarantee of permanence.

Comment: Unless you keep your read-up on the latest releases for OneDrive policy definitions and update correlated registry keys per some change made with a specific Windows version at least in terms of permanence. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/use-group-policy#exclude-specific-kinds-of-files-from-being-uploaded

Answer (score 0):

I figured this topic needed to be updated. You can now exclude chosen file extensions at least from syncing. Would be nice to be able to exclude or use "masking" for more in-depth control of file names. One option is to place files that need to be synced in a separate folder and use another backup program WITH file masking such as Cobian Reflector to copy files to another folder which One Drive is monitoring.

Comment: You can improve your answer by explaining how this can be done.  Give examples,